# Pipeline for image / volume filtering

Tags: c++, vtk

Could anybody design me a pipeline to insert some filters etc. from an vtkDICOMReader ?
Here is the pipeline what I am using now:

```
vtkDICOMReader -> vtkImageReslice -> vtkImageMapToColors
```

and to show image:

```
vtkImageMapToColors -> vtkImageMapper3D -> vtkImageActor -> vtkRenderer
```

and to show volume:

```
vtkDICOMReader -> vtkSmartVolumeMapper -> vtkVolume -> vtkRenderer
```

My experience into VTK are not to far enough to designate a pipeline for filtering image and/or volume ...

I know, there is some examples here: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx
but all of them are based on **vtkPolyDataMapper**, and I have **vtkImageMapper3D** / **vtkSmartVolumeMapper** ... could you draw me a pipeline for any image / volume filter ? Or at least some link to read how to do it ... Thank you in advance.

Flaviu.

Update: how can I implement this filter:
http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Modelling/ExtractLargestIsosurface
into my pipeline, as long in above example, is used **vtkPolyDataConnectivityFilter** ?

Comment: Your question still quite unclear, but in place of `vtkImageReslice` or either side of it, you can add your image-to-image algorithms, e.g., median filter. To create the isosurface as seen behind the link, connect the `vtkImageMarchingCubes` to the imagedata then follow the example. Hope this helps.